# Manage "Dist" repository with Git + Grunt

Tags: javascript, git, version-control, gruntjs

Let's figure I have Git, GruntJS, and two repositories :

- /src/ (my source files for development)
- /dist/ (my compiled/minified files for production)

My "dist" repository is ignored by Git (it's just created or modified by GruntJS).

What's the best way to launch a "grunt" command after a "git push", even if this push is on another remote ?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use [grunt-githooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-githooks)

Comment: @user1677010 What do you mean your dist repo is ignored by git if dist itself is already as a git repo?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do it with git hooks :
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks